# Access modifier of abstract class constructors

Tags: c#, design, .net, access-modifiers

What access modifier should I use for my constructors in an abstract class, given that the class cannot be instantiated?  It seems like the access modifier is superfluous and should be implicitly `protected` since it can only be used from within a derived class' constructor via `base()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, your options are `protected` and `private`.

`protected` seems like a good default, but don't forget about the case where you don't want your sub classes to invoke a specific constructor.  For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractBase
{
    private AbstractBase(int foo, double bar)
    {
        this.CalculatedProperty = someComplexCalculation(foor, bar);
    }

    protected AbstractBase(string XXX, string YYY, int foo, double bar)
        : this(foo, bar)
    {
        this.XXX = XXX;
        this.YYY = YYY;
    }

    protected AbstractBase(string XXX, int foo, double bar)
        : this(XXX, "There is no YYY.  There is only XXX.", foo, bar)
    {
    }

// *snip*

}
```

In this (overly simplified) example, we guarantee that the values for `foo`, `bar`, and `XXX` are always specified and that `CalculatedProperty` and `XXX` are always set.

The private constructor allows us to have shared construction logic without code duplication.  And, because it's private, sub-classes can't accidentally partially construct themselves.

Comment: So what is the purpose of having a `public` constructor, which is not disallowed?

Comment: It's not disallowed, it's simply functionally equivalent to a `protected` constructor.  With that said, I would still avoid using the `public` modifier here simply because if you modify your class in the future and make it **concrete** then your constructor is suddenly more accessible than intended.